# Can I deploy ASP.NET Core MVC program by file copy with USB to multiple Windows 10 PC, like Winforms does?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, publish

I do not know if an ASP.NET Core MVC program can be deployed like a Winforms program, just copy program files.

I am trying to code an ASP.NET Core MVC program. Whenever user type localhost in their PC browser and IIS Web program will show company related documents. Because there are a lot of PCs need to be deployed. So I wonder if I can deploy ASP.NET Core MVC program like Winforms by copying program files.

Comment: ASP.NET Core MVC is a **server-based web** app - it has to be deployed to a **web server** - not to every single end-user PC ...... so ***NO***, it's totally **NOT** like Winforms....

Answer (score 0):

First let me tell you it's ok. Also marc_s' comment is very correct.

I guess I understand your needs. You should install this web application for every user, even if you are not connected to the Internet, you can also access it through localhost.

But what we need to understand is that the asp.net core application should be deployed on the server, so that each user can access the web service by accessing the server ip address or domain name. This is normal operation.

---

You should check the setting about [the single-file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=vs). Then we can get .exe file. Then you can add this .exe file to startup items.

**Reasons for not recommending:**

1. Each of your PCs needs to install the .net core sdk or runtime. This is very unfriendly.
2. If the application needs to access the database, the application cannot run without the network.

Comment: I had raised another question more detail in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74935894/how-to-install-program-which-published-by-vs2017-mvc-project-into-folder, Can you help?